# How to add an ID attribut to xml elements using xslt transformation

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I am very new to xml and xslt transformation. I need some advice.

Basically I have managed to display a range of images from my XML page using XLTR Transformation.

The original xml has no ID's associated with each image, I cant alter the xml. Therefore I was wondering if there was a way in xslt to add an ID attribute to each image before it is outputted to the browser? As I want to be able to control each element/image individually using CSS.

I hope that makes sense?

The xslt is as follows.

```
    <xsl:for-each select=" cars/car_type">

   <!-- <h5> <xsl:value-of select="car-type"/> </h5> -->

 <div class ="images">   
 <img>
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="image"/>

  </xsl:attribute>
</img>
 </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `generate-id` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-generate-id) function to generate an id for an input node e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each select="cars/car_type">
  <div class="images">
    <img src="{image}" id="{generate-id(image)}"/>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

When you create the CSS elsewhere in your stylesheet you simply need to make sure you process the `image` elements again and use `generate-id` again.

Comment: Hi martin, that generates an ID which is great, but every time I refresh the page, the ID obviously changes each time. Therefore How do I would I reference each image. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Martin, I didnt use generate ID, as it was altering every time. so I did this instead which solves my issue. Cheers again.

Comment: <div class ="images">   
 <img src="{image}" id ="car - {position()}">
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="image"/>
   
  </xsl:attribute>
</img>
 </div>